# Do we have the following notation?

Tags: probability

We know that $E[1_{B}]=Pr(B)$. Do we have $E[1_{B}|F]=Pr(B|F)$, where $F$ is $\sigma$-algebra? If yes, what does it mean?

Answer (score 0):

By definition $E[1_B|F]$ must be an $F$ measurable r.v. with $\int_A E[1_B|F]dP=\int_A 1_BdP$ for all $A\in F$. The r.h.s is straightforward: $\int_A 1_BdP = P(A\cap B)$. Thus, $E[1_B|F]$ is zero whenever $B\cap A=\emptyset$. There's some collection of sets $A\in F$ with $A\cap B\neq \emptyset$ so set $E[1_B|F]=P(B\cap A)/ P(A)$, whenever $P(A)\neq 0$ and zero otherwise (check this satisfies the definition!).

Of course $P(B\cap A)/P(A):=P(B|A),$ which gives you back the original, classical definition of conditional probability. Hopefully you can see the advantage of this more abstract definition as it assigns $P(B|A)=0$ whenever $P(A)=0$.